# Includepdf makes extra empty page

Tags: pdf-tools

I have a simple Emacs code to merge a PDF file called "order" at the end of document, but the result has extra empty page with author info at the top.

the code is:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{pdfpages}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{booktabs}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{lastpage}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{authoraftertitle}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a4paper,verbose]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand*\pagemark{%
#+LATEX_HEADER:  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{ \MyTitle ~\pagename~\thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}}%
#+LATEX_HEADER: }
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering\pagemark}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setkomavar{nextfoot}{\centering\pagemark}
#+TITLE:  Here the Title
#+AUTHOR: Name  / number

* Preamble                                                         :noexport:
DEADLINE: <2021-12-01 Wed>

#+SUBJECT: Subject: Here the subject
#+FROM_LOGO: \includegraphics[width=4cm]{./logo.pdf}


#+PLACE: City, Country

#+LCO: DINmtext
# NOTE: Check the KOMA-Script manual to find a LCO that fits the
#       envelope standards of your country.

# NOTE: Change the order of the backletter, use smart quotes and
#       include backaddress
#+OPTIONS: from-logo:t email:nil
#+options: backaddress:t subject:left

# Remove the first header
# #+LATEX_HEADER: \setkomavar{firsthead}{}

* To-address                                                             :to:
# NOTE: Explicit newlines are not necessary in TO and FROM
ABC intern

* From                                                                 :from:
ABC Inc.
Street. 0
00000 City

* 
# NOTE: Your letter is the first non-special heading.  The title of
# this heading may used as an opening.

|   | *Dividing* | *Project / Cost* | *Sum [EUR]* |   |   |
|---+------------+------------------+-------------+---+---|
| # | 2/3        | P123             |          10 |   |   |
| # | 1/3        | P456             |           5 |   |   |
|---+------------+------------------+-------------+---+---|
| $ |            |                  |     max= 15 |   |   |
| # | 1.00       |                  |          15 |   |   |

* order
\includepdf{./order.pdf}
```

this is the extra empty page:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. What's your default LaTeX class? I assume `scrlttr2` but then I get errors in `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents`. When I delete these two from the TeX file and recompile, the compilation finishes without any extra page. So we'll need more information about what exactly you are doing to figure out what's wrong.